# Alternative web browser with adjustable font size?

Tags: browser, accessibility

Is there an alternative WP web browser that lets you change the font size? I have a 4" Lumia and have tried IExplorer, UC Browser, Nokia Express and Maxthon, but they all lack the option to change text size, which on the Lumia 520 is illegible to me.

Note that I'm not interesting in just zooming, because having to scroll sideways back and forth while reading is a pain in the neck. What I'm looking for, is a browser that can change the text size and reflow the pages properly, like Chrome or Opera Mini for Android.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Settings => Easy of Access => Font Size and increase the font size there, built-in Internet Explorer will respect this and increase font size of web pages. It works this way on Windows Phone 8.1 for my Lumia 920.

Comment: No, it doesn't. That setting affects e.g. the standard mail app, but not IE.

Comment: I'm on Windows Phone 8.1 -- its possible this behavior is different if you're on a different version.

Comment: I run WP 8.1 on a Lumia 520. Weirdly, the setting seems to change font size on some non-mobile web sites, but the font on mobile versions are unchanged on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Opera mini beta for Windows Phone. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/opera-mini-beta/b3bf000a-e004-4ecb-a8fb-9fc817cdab90

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't run on Lumia 520. Some reviewers had the same problem, so probably a beta problem that need to be ironed out.